# Why does LibreOffice Calc paste a cell as a graphic?

Tags: libreoffice, copy-and-paste

I have a formula in a cell without additional formatting:

```
=IF(D2>0,F2/(D2),"")
```

When I copied this formula from the first cell down through a range, it was converted to a graphic repeating the results of the first cell over and over.

I was able to test further, and found that I could copy a single cell and paste to the next lower cell, and it worked fine; the second paste to the next lower cell got turned into a graphic again.

Any idea what is happening?

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem in Ubuntu 18.04.4. Bugs are off-topic here. Please go to the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1852183) and mark yourself as affected by the bug. More people indicate that they are affected, more importance the bug will get and higher the chances of it getting fixed soon.

Answer (score 3):

Because you are experiencing a bug. You did not tell, but you are using Ubuntu 19.10 or later. The Gnome developpers recoded clipboard functionality in a more recent version of window manager mutter, and as a result, the clipboard is a little broken right now. One of the more visible side effects is what you see now in Calc, but also in other occasions, you will experience that sometimes some older entry than the one you see are pasted. You will, like myself, blame it on yourself, but no, it is a current issue. I hope it will be corrected anytime soon. Currently, also Ubuntu 20.04 is plagued.

*Workaround*:

- Use the Wayland display server instead of Xorg (but that has other issues). The issue of mutter is only with xorg.
- Alternatively, be very careful with copy/paste and double check. Systematically pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> twice will in most cases be fine.

See the [Ubuntu bug report here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1852183).

Answer (score -1):

I did some more research, and found a [relevant question](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/213510/copypaste-clipboard-issues-libreoffice-calc/?answer=224835#post-id-224835) on libreoffice.org that suggests a copy manager may be to blame. My first thought was that I wasn't running one, since I didn't see any related logos and I'm not running Mutter (the compositor for Ubuntu 19 - I'm running Ubuntu 16).

However, since I've run copy managers in the past, I did a double-check:

```
$ ps auwx| grep copy
emd       7741  0.0  0.4 2913064 59788 ?       Sl   Apr04   0:46 /usr/bin/copyq
emd       8058  0.0  0.1 416384 14652 ?        Sl   Apr04   0:20 
/usr/bin/copyq monitor /home/emd/.config/copyq/.copyq_m
emd      25726  0.0  0.0  20504   932 pts/7    S+   11:36   0:00 grep copy
```

So this shows me that the copy manager [copyq](https://sourceforge.net/projects/copyq/) was running. I killed it:

```
$ pkill copyq
```

Now things are working better - except now if I copy a formula that resolves to a number, it pastes the result (number) into the next cell not the formula as it does otherwise.

Not a good sign when I run into bugs almost immediately upon the first time using this software in a long time - how many new users bail out instead of going to all the trouble that I have?

Comment: Is this an answer to your question or more information related to the question? If it is the latter please delete and add the new new information to the question.